# Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry':

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm facing the following issue. I've started migrating my app to react and i've created my first module. So I have my legacy code which is loading my react app bundle.js so I can use the new react module.

When I use my navigation to go to the new react module everything works fine. When I use the same link again I get the following error and the page is blank:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "input-mask" has already been used with this registry

Any suggestions to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. These two references coexisted in the same javascript file.

```
require("inputmask");
require("inputmask/dist/jquery.inputmask.js");
```

Removing the first one solved the issue for me.